# How to avoid "Duplicate type name within an assembly" while reusing ScriptEngine with anonymouse type?

Tags: c#, anonymous-types, roslyn

I'm working with scripting rules engine based on [roslyn-ctp](/questions/tagged/roslyn-ctp) that will process `IEnumerable<T>` and returns results as `IEnumerable<T>`. To avoid creating of `ScriptEngine`, configuring and parsing again and again, I'd like to reuse one instance of `ScriptEngine`.

Here is a short sample ([full sample at *gist.github.com*](https://gist.github.com/akimboyko/5193989)):

```
var engine = new ScriptEngine();

new[]
{
    typeof (Math).Assembly,
    this.GetType().Assembly
}.ToList().ForEach(assembly => engine.AddReference(assembly));

new[]
{
    "System", "System.Math", 
    typeof(Model.ProcessingModel).Namespace
} .ToList().ForEach(@namespace => engine.ImportNamespace(@namespace));

IEnumerable<Model.ProcessingModel> models = new[]
{
    new Model.ProcessingModel { InputA = 10M, InputB = 5M, Factor = 0.050M },
    new Model.ProcessingModel { InputA = 20M, InputB = 2M, Factor = 0.020M },
    new Model.ProcessingModel { InputA = 12M, InputB = 3M, Factor = 0.075M }
};

// no dynamic allowed
// anonymous class are duplicated in assembly
var script =
    @"
    Result = InputA + InputB * Factor;
    Delta = Math.Abs((Result ?? 0M) - InputA);
    Description = ""Some description"";
    var result = new { Σ = Result, Δ = Delta, λ = Description };
    result
    ";

// Here is ArgumentException `Duplicate type name within an assembly`
IEnumerable<dynamic> results =
                models.Select(model => engine.CreateSession(model).Execute(script));
```

And here are several issues:

- [roslyn-ctp](/questions/tagged/roslyn-ctp) does not support `dynamic` keyword
- **While using anonymous types inside script I get an exception `Duplicate type name within an assembly`** when [rsolyn-ctp](/questions/tagged/rsolyn-ctp) is creating assembly using `System.Reflection.Emit`

### Question

Is there way to create `ScriptEngine` and reuse it many times when script contains anonymous type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're hitting a bug in Roslyn.

I'd recommend not compiling the script in a loop. Since the code doesn't change it is much more efficient to only update the data the script is working with. Such approach also avoids the bug.

```
var model = new Model();
var session = engine.CreateSession(model);
var submission = session.CompileSubmission<dynamic>(script);
foreach (Model data in models)
{
    model.InputA = data.InputA;
    model.InputB = data.InputB;
    model.Factor = data.Factor;

    dynamic result = submission.Execute();
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", result.Σ, result.Δ, result.λ);
}
```

Comment: Thx, it works fine. I have updated sample at [gist.github.com](https://gist.github.com/akimboyko/5193989)